# MAUI codebehind binding a Entry Text to an dictionary value

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I would like to bind the property Text of an Entry to a Value of a Dictionary in the Code Behind of my XAML.
Currently this works only conditionally. If I specify the value in the dictionary, then this neatly displayed in the property text. However, if I change the value in the Entry, then it is not changed in the Dictionary.

I create a new entry during the runtime. The value is read from the dictionary and also displayed correctly.
Unfortunately it works only in one direction. Writing a new value in the dictionary is not done.

```
var entry = new Entry {
    Placeholder = item.Key,
    ClassId = item.Key,
    Text = (String)keyValuePairs.Where(k => k.Key == item.Key).First().Value
};
```

In this case: the keyValuePairs is a Observable Property in the viewModel

Comment: You are assigning a static string value, not creating a binding

Comment: @Jason Binding in xaml with Text = {Binding ...Value} it is clear to me how this works. But how do I do that in the code behind?

Comment: Use [SetBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: @Jason this works only conditionally. If I specify an empty variable for setbinding, then I get the exception "path can not be empty". But the value must be empty.

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: @Jason `entry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, (BindingBase)_viewModel.ResultsKeyValues[item.Key]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, path syntax is tricky and weird. But this should work.

```
entry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, $"{nameof(_viewModel.ResultsKeyValues)}[{item.Key}]");
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
entry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "dict[MyKey]");
```